# What is ¬ called and what is it for?

Tags: programming-languages

*Googling* this question has proved somewhat useless, so the `¬` symbol:

- What is it for?
- What is is called?
- Is it used in any programming languages?

Comment: That character is `U+00AC NOT SIGN` and is [one of the many notations for logical negation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negation#Notation)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about *software development concepts* as explained in the [help/on-topic].

Comment: Where did you see this symbol?

Comment: It's on a standard UK 101 keyboard, top left with the back tick ` ` ` and the broken pipe `¦`.

Comment: Wikipedia has redirects for many unicode symbols.  [¬](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=¬&redirect=no).  You can also see this with things like [](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=&redirect=no).  While google's search doesn't do a good job with this character, one should try pasting it into Wikipedia's search. They have [many redirects for single unicode characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Redirects_from_Unicode_characters) set up.

Comment: Used to break long statements in app script http://alvinalexander.com/mac-os-x/mac-osx-applescript-break-long-lines-keytroke

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The only use I've seen for the `¬` symbol is to represent negation in the context of formal logic. For instance, if `P` is the proposition "It will rain today", then `¬P` is the proposition "It will not rain today." I've also seen ~ used for this.

I don't believe it has an actual name other than "negation symbol". Normally it's read as "not".

As far as I know, in programming this symbol has no special meaning, at least not in any mainstream languages I've used.

Comment: Some programming languages accept UTF8 characters as names or user-defined operators.

Comment: Why is *negation symbol* not an "actual name"? After all, we call ! *exclamation point* and ? *question mark*. And those are perfectly fine names.

Comment: [REXX uses ¬ for logical not](http://www.oorexx.org/docs/rexxref/x974.htm) and in operators like `¬=`, `¬>`, etc. Most implementation also allow `\\` because many keyboards lack a ¬ key. I'm not sure that it can be considered a mainstream language, though.

Comment: PL/1 (developed in the late 1960s) used the ¬ symbol for not. Having used PL/1 for many years I still think of this as the _not_ symbol

Comment: AppleScript uses ¬ as the [line-continuation symbol](http://applescript.wikia.com/wiki/Line-Continuation_Symbol), to split long commands into multiple lines, like \ in bash script.